# PHP $this when not in object context for set public variable from out of class

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop, static

I have simple class and I want to set `public` variable from out of class.

```
<?php

class AlachiqHelpers
{
    public $height;

    public static function getHeight($height)
    {
        return $this->height - 50;
    }

    public static function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }
}
```

In Result i get this error:

> ```
> Using $this when not in object context
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The `$this` keyword cannot be used under static context !.

**Case 1:**

You need to remove the `static` keyword from the function defintion.

Instead of

```
public static function setHeight( $height ){
```

Should be

```
public function setHeight( $height ){
```

---

**Case 2:**

If you really need to make it(function) as `static`... You could just use the `self` keyword to access the variable..

```
public static $height;
public static function setHeight( $height )
{
    self::$height=22;
}
```

Keep in mind that the `$height` variable is also made `static`

---

#### The working code.. (static one)

```
<?php
class AlachiqHelpers
{
    public static $height;
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return self::$height - 50;
    }

    public static function setHeight($height1)
    {
        self::$height = $height1;
    }
}

$a = new AlachiqHelpers();
$a->setHeight(180);
echo $a->getHeight();
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
130
```

Comment: To add to this, if you truly need static methods, which you should verify if you do or not.  You need to access properties, or variables, with `static::$variable` or `self::$variable` rather than `$this->variable`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `static`, these methods should not be static method but instance method.

`$this` can not be used under static context, because static context is shared by all the instances but not a single one.

Static method can only access the static property.

Non-static method can access both non-static property (by `$this->foo`) and static property(by `self::$foo`).

Answer (score 0):

[**`Source`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

You can't use `$this` inside a static function, because static functions are independent of any instantiated object.

Try making the function not static.

```
public  function setHeight( $height ){

        $this->height=$height;

    }
```